# How can I get Emacs to indent my // comments with my code?

Tags: c++, c, emacs

I don't know much about Emacs, but after some googling, I edited my `.emacs` file to be as follows:

```
(setq c-default-style "bsd" c-basic-offset 4)
```

My goal was to get Allman-style indenting with 4-spaced tabs. It works as expected, but now my `//` comments aren't indented with my code. Before I changed this, when I would type `//`, it would get auto-indented to be in line with the rest of the code in the function. How can I get Emacs to auto-indent `//` comments?

I've tried adding `c-indent-comments-syntactically-p 1` to the above `.emacs` file, but that didn't change it...

For example:

```
int main()
{
    // I'd like this line to be auto-indented to match the block
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        // And this line to be auto-indented to match the block
        doStuff();
    }
}
```

Currently, `TAB` does not indent my `//` comment, and it doesn't automatically indent either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can inspect and change the value of the current indent by placing point on the concerned line and pressing `C-c C-o`. Adjust the relevant symbols to your liking.

This wont be permanent. Use direct invocation of the function `c-set-offset` in your `.emacs` to make the changes globally.

Simple example:

```
int main() {
  // 
}
```

This is my default indent. After moving the cursor to line 2 I see that the relevant symbol is `comment-intro`.

Using:

```
(c-set-offset 'comment-intro 6)
```

I get:

```
int main() {
        //
}
```

Offset accumulates across symbols:

```
int main() {
        //
  {
          //
  }
}
```

Comment: But what if it's a nested block?

Comment: @Cornstalks offset is relative to the surrounding offset. I added an example.

Comment: Awesome. Given my little `.emacs` file from above, what would be the proper way to add this? Putting `(setq c-default-style "bsd" c-basic-offset 4 (c-set-offset 'comment-intro 4))` in my `.emacs` file makes Emacs barf with the error: `Wrong type argument: symbolp, (c-set-offset (quote comment-intro) 4)`

Comment: `setq` and `c-set-offset` should be two separate LISP expressions at the same level, like this: `(setq c-default-style "bsd" c-basic-offset 4)(c-set-offset 'comment-intro 4)`

Comment: @Francesco: Perfect, thanks! I added `(c-set-offset 'comment-intro 0)` and it works just fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Hitting TAB still indents your comment line, right?  Then what you're missing is the automatic recognition of the double-slash triggering the autoindentation.  That is implemented by (c-electric-slash).  First be sure that slash is still bound to that command:
`C-h k /` (help on keystroke slash).  Then, assuming the documentation for c-electric-slash shows up, read it to figure out under what conditions it's inhibited.

Comment: Nope. TAB no longer indents the comment. I'll edit my question to mention that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put your comment on the same alignement of your code scope, just add the folllowing line to your **~/.emacs** file:

```
(c-set-offset 'comment-intro 0)
```